# OK to use controller as delegate and data datasource for uitableview in iOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it ok to use your view controller as your uiview's delegate, it seems to make sense to be as they are similar in nature.

More specifically is it OK to use your uitableviewcontroller as your uitableview's delegate and data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

And UITableViewController already *is* the `.delegate` and `.dataSource` of its UITableView by default.